# Cancel and done button does not work in new contact view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to integrate new contact control in my app. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL) personViewController:(ABPersonViewController*)personView shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue 
{ 
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)addcontact:(id)sender{

    ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

    [picker release];
    [navigation release];

}
```

It pops up new contact view but when I click **Cancel** or **Done** button nothing happens. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having the same problem. When i click Done nothing happens. Did you get the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add methods that should be called when the cancel or done button is tapped and that method should call `[self.navigationController dismissModalViewController`

Answer (score 4):

```
//Make sure your VC is an <ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate>
-(void) newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView 
    didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

if (person != nil)  //nil = Cancel button clicked
{
  //do something  
}

//iOS6
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```